# dplyr will not filter or mutate by time -- any other way to do this?

Tags: dplyr, time, mutate

I am trying to create a new column in my dataset that defines time of day (TOD) of the entry. Dataset looks something like this:

| ID | conc | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 20001 | 2022-01-04 | 21:32:40 |
| 02 | 23090 | 2022-01-04 | 00:33:20 |
| 03 | 23546 | 2022-01-04 | 13:04:15 |
| 04 | 24908 | 2022-01-04 | 09:12:03 |

I am trying to add a new column, TOD, to define these as "early morning", "morning", "afternoon", "evening", "night". Looks something like this:

| ID | conc | date | time | TOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 20001 | 2022-01-04 | 21:32:40 | night |
| 02 | 23090 | 2022-01-04 | 00:33:20 | early morning |
| 03 | 23546 | 2022-01-04 | 13:04:15 | afternoon |
| 04 | 24908 | 2022-01-04 | 09:12:03 | morning |

I've written code like this using dplyr to mutate by time specifications but for some reason this isn't working this time around, and it is driving me crazy.

I've tried iterations of the following code:

```
mobile2022 <- mobile2022 %>%  
  mutate(TOD = case_when(time >= hms("00:00:00") & time <= hms("04:59:59") ~ "early morning",
                         time >= hms("05:00:00") & time <= hms("09:59:59") ~ "morning",
                         time >= hms("10:00:00") & time <= hms("14:59:59") ~ "afternoon",
                         time >= hms("15:00:00") & time <= hms("18:59:59") ~ "evening",
                         TRUE ~ "night"))
```

I don't get any error codes, I just get either all NAs or all "night." I've tried using hm() and just keeping the hour and minute, I've tried putting these into ifelse statements, I've reformatted "time" over and over again (using hms() and as.POSIXct()), none of which have worked.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to extract the `hour()` component of your `time` variable, and apply your `case_when()` conditions to label the time-of-day.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(hr = hour(hms(time)),
         TOD = case_when(hr >= 0 & hr < 5 ~ 'early morning',
                         hr >= 5 & hr < 10 ~ 'morning',
                         hr >= 10 & hr < 15 ~ 'afternoon',
                         hr >= 15 & hr < 19 ~ 'evening',
                         TRUE ~ 'night')) %>%
  select(-hr)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   ID     conc date       time     TOD          
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>        
#> 1 01    20001 2022-01-04 21:32:40 night        
#> 2 02    23090 2022-01-04 00:33:20 early morning
#> 3 03    23546 2022-01-04 13:04:15 afternoon    
#> 4 04    24908 2022-01-04 09:12:03 morning
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>